# Can we set custom data while creating a Private QBDialog?

Tags: android, quickblox

I am using QuickBlox Android SDK. While creating a new private dialog, I need to add some meta data in QBDialog.

As I understand, a private dialog should be created using PrivateChatManager.  And it only provides a way to create a dialog with participant ID with following method signature.

*createDialog(int participantID)*

But according to my requirement, I need to pass some other meta data like the name of the participant. That is required while retrieving the Dialogs. 
Otherwise, I will have to do a separate API call to get the user details!

So, Can't we pass meta data to a private Chat Dialog? Are there any solutions to overcome this problem?

Comment: One approach could be, fetch QBUser by id and save into local db. When you fetch QBDialogs you can get occupant ids. Fetch profiles of those occupant ids and show opponent name for that dialog.

Comment: Yeah. It needed a little more effort but I finally, went with this approach only. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the following workaround with custom parameters:

[custom parameters](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Custom_parameters)